# ajax is working but form data not getting submitted

Tags: php, ajax, contact-form, ajaxform

im using a ajax contact form that fades out and shows a thank you message.And I also get the mail after i submit the form.But it doesn't have any data that is entered in the form.I think the form data is not getting passed on to handler.php..Any helps please?

ajax.js

```
$(function() {

var theForm = $("#memberform");

theForm.validate({

submitHandler: function(theForm) {

$('#loader', theForm).html('Please Wait...');

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "handler.php",
data: $(theForm).serialize(),
timeout: 20000,

    success: function(msg) { $(theForm).fadeOut((500, function(){ 

                $(theForm).html("<h2>Thank you. We will contact you shortly.</h2>").fadeIn(); 

                }));
            },

            error: $('.thanks').show()

        });

        return false;
    }
   });
});
```

handler.php

```
<?php


$to      = 'something@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Contact Form';

$name = $_POST['senderName'];
$phone = $_POST['senderNumber'];
$email = $_POST['senderEmail'];
$message = $_POST['senderComments'];

$MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$name."<br>"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Contact No: ".$phone."<br>"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: ".$email."<br>"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Message: ".nl2br($message)."<br>"; 

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'From: Companyname' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: something.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: something@gmail.com' . "\r\n";
//$headers .= 'Bcc: example@example.com' . "\r\n";


mail($to, $subject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $headers);


?
```

scripts i linked in head tag on top of the body tag.

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="met.js"></script>
```

and I edited the web.config file with the rewrite rule to hide .php extentions from domain...

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
    <rule name="Hide .php ext">
        <match ignoreCase="true" url="^(.*)"/>
        <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php" matchType="IsFile"/>
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.php"/>
    </rule>
    <rule name="Redirecting .php ext" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^(.*).php"/>
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*).php"/>
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}"/>
    </rule>
   </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Instead of `$(theForm).serialize()` try `theForm.serialize()`. It's already a jQuery object, no need to pass it through jQuery again.

Comment: hi,Thanks for the help.After editing, the ajax is not working at all.It redirects to handler.php and stays without any changes. @maiorano84

Comment: Where is the actual form that you serialize?

Answer (score 0):

Try this , maybe helpful

```
$(function() {
var theForm = $("#memberform");
var data =  theForm.serialize();
theForm.validate({
    submitHandler: function(theForm) {
        $('#loader', theForm).html('Please Wait...');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "handler.php",
            data: data,
            timeout: 20000,
            success: function(msg) { $(theForm).fadeOut((500, function(){ 
                    $(theForm).html("<h2>Thank you. We will contact you shortly.</h2>").fadeIn();
                }));
            },
            error: $('.thanks').show();
        });return false;
    }
   });
});
```

Comment: not working my friend... ajax not working.It redirects to handler.php only.

Comment: okay , in handler.php write  *echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);exit;* and chcek is data are parsing from ajax or not

Comment: im not quite pro in php... so should I remove all contents in handler.php and write the above code? so what about ajax.js..should i edit anything on that? @Soni Vimal

Comment: no just write this line in before starting of your code

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping me with the problem.Just found the answer by deleting some rewrite rule.The problem is in web.config.Removing the rewrite rule makes the form work just fine...

Or if you want to keep the rewrite rule and submit the form, edit the 
---url: "handler.php"--- line to url: "handler" and the form works just fine.